# Getting multiple results with one button (python/ tkiner)

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm a beginner, and I've gathered a number of reference sites to make code!

But if you click the button, you'll see the value only for the last item.

Do you happen to know how to get each result in every row! And now you have to enter all the items to get the value, but even if there is a blank, I hope the result will come out for all the input boxes.

I think the code is a little tangled, but it's hard to solve. I'm posting the code's full text.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import csv

class App(ttk.Frame):
    num_rows = 2
    entry_list = []

    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs)
        self.master = master
        self.label_frame = ttk.Frame(self.master)
        self.label_frame.grid()
        self.label_list = []

        label1 = Label(root, width=5, text="No.")
        label2 = Label(root, width=12, text="Chip")
        label3 = Label(root, width=12, text="Length[mm] : ")
        label4 = Label(root, width=12, text="Width[mm] : ")
        label5 = Label(root, width=12, text="Height[mm] : ")
        label6 = Label(root, width=12, text="Watt[W] : ")
        label7 = Label(root, width=12, text="Rjc[C/W] : ")
        label8 = Label(root, width=12, text="h[W/㎡K] : ")
        label9 = Label(master, width=12, text="Temp[C] : ",fg='red')

        #grid
        label1.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=1, pady=10)
        label2.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=2, pady=10)
        label3.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=2, pady=10)
        label4.grid(row=0, column=3, padx=2, pady=10)
        label5.grid(row=0, column=4, padx=2, pady=10)
        label6.grid(row=0, column=5, padx=2, pady=10)
        label7.grid(row=0, column=6, padx=2, pady=10)
        label8.grid(row=0, column=7, padx=2, pady=10)
        label9.grid(row=0, column=8, padx=2, pady=10)


        ##유동
        self.Number_field = Entry(root, width=5)
        self.Length_field = Entry(root, width=9)
        self.Width_field = Entry(root, width=9)
        self.Height_field = Entry(root, width=9)
        self.Watt_field = Entry(root, width=9)
        self.Rjc_field = Entry(root, width=9)
        self.Temperature_field = Entry(root, width=9)

        self.Number_field.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=1, pady=1)
        self.Length_field.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=1, pady=1)
        self.Width_field.grid(row=1, column=3, padx=1, pady=1)
        self.Height_field.grid(row=1, column=4, padx=1, pady=1)
        self.Watt_field.grid(row=1, column=5, padx=1, pady=1)
        self.Rjc_field.grid(row=1, column=6, padx=1, pady=1)
        self.Temperature_field.grid(row=1, column=8, padx=1, pady=1)

        strs = StringVar()
        strs2 = StringVar()
        combx1 = ttk.Combobox(root, width=9, textvariable=strs)

        combx1['values'] = (' Natural', ' Forced(Fan)')
        combx1.current()
        combx1.grid(column=7, row=1)

        combx2 = ttk.Combobox(root, width=9, textvariable=strs2)
        combx2['values'] = ('CPU', 'eMMC', 'PMIC')
        combx2.grid(column=1, row=1)
        combx2.current()

        # Create a Submit Button and attached

        button1 = Button(root, text="Submit", bg="black", fg="white", command=self.cal_Temp)
        button1.grid(row=100, column=0, pady=10)
        button2 = Button(root, text="Clear", fg="blue", command=self.clear_all)
        button2.grid(row=100, column=1, pady=10)
        button3 = Button(root, text="Add Row (+)",  command=self.add_new)
        button3.grid(row=102, column=0, pady=10)
        button4 = Button(root, text="Delete Row (-)", command=self.delete)
        button4.grid(row=102, column=1, pady=10)
        button5 = Button(root, text="Export", command=self.writeToFile)
        button5.grid(row=103, column=1, pady=10)


    def writeToFile(self):
        with open('Temperature_MJH.csv', 'a') as f:
            w=csv.writer(f, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

            w.writerow([self.Length_field.get()])
            w.writerow([self.Width_field.get()])
            w.writerow([self.Height_field.get()])
            w.writerow([self.Watt_field.get()])
            w.writerow([self.Rjc_field.get()])
            w.writerow([self.Temperature_field.get()])


    def clear_all(self):
        self.Number_field.delete(0,END)
        self.Length_field.delete(0, END)
        self.Width_field.delete(0, END)
        self.Height_field.delete(0, END)
        self.Watt_field.delete(0, END)
        self.Rjc_field.delete(0, END)
        self.Temperature_field.delete(0, END)



        #이거 지워도 되는지
        self.Length_field.focus_set()

    def cal_Temp(self):
        Length = float(self.Length_field.get())
        Width = float(self.Width_field.get())
        Height = float(self.Height_field.get())
        Watt = float(self.Watt_field.get())
        Rjc = float(self.Rjc_field.get())
        h = 1

        Temperature = float(((Watt * 0.5) / (((Length * Width * 2) + (Length * 2) + (
                    Height * Width * 5)) / 1000)) / h + Rjc )
        self.Temperature_field.insert(10,Temperature)
        print(Temperature)


    def add_new(self):


        self.num_rows += 1


        self.Number_field = Entry(root, width=5)
        self.Length_field = Entry(root, width=9)
        self.Width_field = Entry(root, width=9)
        self.Height_field = Entry(root, width=9)
        self.Watt_field = Entry(root, width=9)
        self.Rjc_field = Entry(root, width=9)
        self.Temperature_field = Entry(root, width=9)

        self.Number_field.grid(row=self.num_rows, column=0, padx=1, pady=1)
        self.Length_field.grid(row=self.num_rows, column=2, padx=1, pady=1)
        self.Width_field.grid(row=self.num_rows, column=3, padx=1, pady=1)
        self.Height_field.grid(row=self.num_rows, column=4, padx=1, pady=1)
        self.Watt_field.grid(row=self.num_rows, column=5, padx=1, pady=1)
        self.Rjc_field.grid(row=self.num_rows, column=6, padx=1, pady=1)
        self.Temperature_field.grid(row=self.num_rows, column=8, padx=1, pady=1)



        strs = StringVar()
        strs2 = StringVar()
        self.combx1 = ttk.Combobox(root, width=9, textvariable=strs)

        self.combx1['values'] = (' Natural', ' Forced(Fan)')
        self.combx1.current()
        self.combx1.grid(row=self.num_rows, column=7)

        self.combx2 = ttk.Combobox(root, width=9, textvariable=strs2)
        self.combx2['values'] = ('CPU', 'eMMC', 'PMIC')
        self.combx2.grid(row=self.num_rows, column=1)
        self.combx2.current()
        self.ics=self.num_rows
        self.Number_field.insert(10, self.ics-1)


    def delete(self):
        self.num_rows -= 1
        self.Number_field.destroy()
        self.Length_field.destroy()
        self.Width_field.destroy()
        self.Height_field.destroy()
        self.Watt_field.destroy()
        self.Rjc_field.destroy()
        self.Temperature_field.destroy()
        self.combx1.destroy()
        self.combx2.destroy()


        self.ics -= 1




if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    root.configure(background='snow')
    root.geometry("1000x450")
    root.title("Expectation of Temp Calculator")
    my_app = App(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Of course you are only printing the temperature, not the value of ```StringVar```

Comment: You used same set of instance variables to hold the entries and comboboxes in each row, so those instance variables will refer to the last set created.  You need to use a list to store the set of instance variables for each row.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm a beginner, is it hard to use the list with this code? Do I have to modify the list from the beginning to use it? Thank you.